# Why doesn't group policy settingS get changed?

Tags: c#, group-policy

I am trying to change some windows settings by group policy settings using C#.
My application creates sub-keys in the  group policy objects section successfully, 
But some times they doesn't work.
For example i am trying to disable desktop using Group policy, I take these steps :

1. I run `Process monitor` and configure it to show me the registry changes relating to mmc.exe
2. Then run gpedit.msc and navigate to the desired option and change it
3. I copy the registry change which is shown in `Process monitor` and use it
   in my app like this :

   ```
   mmc.exe  RegSetValue HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{FD0F8A58-1909-410F-8860-4CFF7766FA89}User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDesktop        SUCCESS  Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 1
   ```

And use it like this :

```
string regPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer";
string option = "NoDesktop";

SetGroupPolicySetting(regPath, option, 1);
```

SetGroupPolicySetting uses a dll which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows/comment-page-1) and is written like this :

```
private void SetGroupPolicySetting(string registryKeyPath,
                                    string option,
                                    int value ,
                                    GroupPolicySection groupPolicySection = GroupPolicySection.User)
{
    var gpo = new ComputerGroupPolicyObject();
    RegistryKey registryKey = gpo.GetRootRegistryKey(groupPolicySection);
    registryKey.CreateSubKey(registryKeyPath).SetValue(option, value , RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    gpo.Save();
}
```

After that , there are two subkeys created which are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{27D2FEFF-E5C6-4D8B-B657-0D1E1F2E4BAE}Machine
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{27D2FEFF-E5C6-4D8B-B657-0D1E1F2E4BAE}User
```

and finally the NoDesktop option in Explorer section is created in this address :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{27D2FEFF-E5C6-4D8B-B657-0D1E1F2E4BAE}User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

though still its not working ! Whats wrong ? its driving me insane!

Comment: Direct poking of the registry has never been a supported way to change GP objects. It's possible the `gpedit.msc` makes this registry change and then does *something else* that you're not capturing (or the other way around)

Comment: The catch is some settings work this way some time , and the same settings doesnt work at some other times!!! no desktop used to work but now it doesnt!!

Comment: But that's what happens when you go down the unsupported route. Windows 9 *could* make writing a 1 to that registry location format your hard drive. I believe that the registry locations are only *documented* so that you can *read* GP information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a GPO alone does not make it active. GPOs usually get reapplied at boot or after a certain period of time. You can probably run something like [`gpupdate /force`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490983.aspx) (as Administrator) to force reapplying GPOs.

Comment: Thank you very much ;) so far so good and everything is working just fine ;)